# Drawing repetitively one canvas without that edges become dark

Tags: html, image, canvas, drawing

I have this code that for some reason it should draw `canvas` many times (using `setTimeout`):

```
function drawImage() {
    var img = new Image();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("event");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    img.src = "../img/event.png";
    img.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   }
   setTimeout(drawImage, 3000);
}
```

but it cause dark edge as draw more times as this:

[image: dark edge]

Is it possible to prevent edges become dark in repetitively drawing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the image has an alpha-channel you cannot avoid this when re-painting it over and over without some mechanism to reset the alpha values drawn.

The reason for this is that the alpha-value for that pixel will accumulate so when you draw a non-opaque edge (or anti-aliased edge) on top of each other the value for the alpha channel will be added to the value already drawn resulting in that the edge will be more and more visible.

There are fortunately a couple of ways to avoid this:

**A)** If you want to keep the alpha-channel in the image use `clearRect` before drawing the image.

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

This will clear the canvas and the alpha channel.

<kbd>**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Nz6nn/6/)**</kbd>

[image]

**B)** If alpha channel is not important save out the image without any alpha-channel (use PNG with transparency off or use JPEG).

Also a note to your loop in the example - this is *not* a good way to redraw an image as you are initiating a load/cache check as well as image decoding each time.

You can modify your code as this (adopt as you please):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("event");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = document.createElement('img'); // due to chrome bug
img.onload = drawImage;                  // set onload first

img.src = "../img/event.png";            // src last..

function drawImage() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    setTimeout(drawImage, 3000);
}
```